# Creating Linked List dynamically in C

Tags: c, struct, linked-list

I'm trying to create a linked list dynamically in `c` using structures and print it. But my below code is throwing runtime error can anybody tell me why I am getting this error. Here is my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
struct cnode
{
    int value;
    struct cnode *next;
};

void print_list(struct cnode* start)
{
    while(start->next != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d->", start->value);
        start = start->next;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    int i,n,val;
    //List length
    scanf("%d", &n);

    //Head
    struct cnode* start;
    scanf("%d", &val);
    start->value = val;

    struct cnode* temp = start;

    for (i=1; i<=n-1; i++)
    {
        struct cnode* node;
        scanf("%d", &val);
        node->value = val;

        temp->next = node;
        temp = node;
    }
    temp->next = NULL;

    print_list(start);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Undefined behavior for using the value of an object with automatic storage duration while it is indeterminate.

Comment: So you want to create a linked list dynamically, but you don't allocate anything?  Does something there ring a bell for you?

Comment: Although you provided enough information to enable a few useful answers, you could _[improve your question](http://sscce.org/)_ by being more specific on _what_ runtime errors were thrown.  Other than that, I am not sure why the down-votes.

Comment: @dbush answered this question very well. [Here](http://ideone.com/nK45vZ) is an example that properly uses `malloc` and `free`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're failing to allocate memory for the pointers to point to.  You need to call `malloc` to do that.

```
struct cnode *start = malloc(sizeof(struct cnode));
if (start == NULL) {
    perror("malloc failed");
    exit(1);
}

...

struct cnode *node= malloc(sizeof(struct cnode));
if (node == NULL) {
    perror("malloc failed");
    exit(1);
}
```

Also, when printing the list you're not printing the last value.

```
while(start != NULL)
{
    printf("%d->", start->value);
    start = start->next;
}
```

Don't forget to free the memory when you're done.

```
print_list(start);

while (start != NULL) {
    temp = start;
    start = start->next;
    free(temp);
}

return 0;
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's one problem:

When you write "struct cnode * node;" you are asking the compiler to create a pointer to a structure.  But there is no memory allocated for that structure.  When you write "node->value = val" you are asking the machine to store the value of val into unallocated memory, whatever garbage happens to be in "node".  You need to use malloc to actually allocate the memory and then store the pointer to that memory in the "node" variable.